# NumberFormatException: For input string "\N" when reading from file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from a large data file movies.dat and then populate my database table with certain columns of that data.

The data in the movies file has the following data fields/columns:

id  title   imdbID  spanishTitle    imdbPictureURL  year    rtID    rtAllCriticsRating  rtAllCriticsNumReviews  rtAllCriticsNumFresh    rtAllCriticsNumRotten   rtAllCriticsScore   rtTopCriticsRating  rtTopCriticsNumReviews  rtTopCriticsNumFresh    rtTopCriticsNumRotten   rtTopCriticsScore   rtAudienceRating    rtAudienceNumRatings    rtAudienceScore rtPictureURL

The data values are separated by tabs.

```
    String line;

    // open movies file
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Michael\\IdeaProjects\\hw3\\data\\movies.dat"));
    System.out.println("Movies.dat successfully opened.");

    // read the first line (header) of file
    line = reader.readLine();

    // create PreparedStatement for inserting movie data into db
    try {
        PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO Movie(mID, movieTitle, releaseYear, "
                        + "allCriticsRating, allCriticsNumReviews, "
                        + "topCriticsRating, topCriticsNumReviews, "
                        + "audienceRating, audienceNumRatings) "
                        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        // read remaining lines of data in the file
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // separate each data field value and store into tmp array
            String[] tmp = line.split("\\t");

            s.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]));
            s.setString(2, tmp[1]);
            s.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(tmp[5]));
            s.setFloat(4, Float.parseFloat(tmp[7]));
            s.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(tmp[8]));
            s.setFloat(6, Float.parseFloat(tmp[12]));
            s.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(tmp[13]));
            s.setFloat(8, Float.parseFloat(tmp[17]));
            s.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(tmp[18]));

            s.addBatch();
        }
        s.executeBatch();
        s.close();
        System.out.println("Movie table successfully populated!");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Movie table population failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, when I run this code, I'm getting a numberformatexception for input string "\N" on the first parseFloat. I don't understand where the "\n" could be coming from though. I've used this same code (adjusted for some different data fields) to populate my other tables with data from another file and it worked fine so I'm not sure why it's just this file that's giving me issues.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: `\n` stand for new line. Did you debug to see the value for `line`?

Comment: @mc2017 I think we need a little more context to help you out. Is there anyway you can cut and paste the raw string from your .dat file for the row that it is failing on?

Comment: Can you log `line` before splitting it?

Comment: Ah, so I think I might have figured out the problem. I looked through the file and there are actual values "\N" under the ratings columns scattered throughout the file that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If the error message literally says "\N", then more likely the file literally contains "\N" (as in a backslash followed by a capital N, not a linebreak).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well one time I was doing a web page parser and when got the string include the `\n` as part of the string  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You can update this line:

> > String[] tmp = line.split("\t");

to look like this

> > String[] tmp = line.strip().split("\t");

and the excess whitespace before and after the tokens will be removed (including the new line character)